# Returning errors with Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an endpoint generated as follows:

```
public Book insertBook(Book book) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        if (containsShout(book)) {
            throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
        }
        mgr.makePersistent(book);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return book;
}
```

I wonder how I should return errors to the client.
E.g. the book contains some required fields, an ISNM check etc.

So I would assume throwing an exception but how does this map to the returned json response.
The json repsonse should contain all field errors to highlight these fields in the client.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? If how did you do it?

Comment: No, but I'm not interested anymore

Answer (score 5):

In general exceptions are mapped to a 500 http status code in the response. With the following exceptions you can get different codes:
`com.google.api.server.spi.response.BadRequestException` -> 400
`com.google.api.server.spi.response.UnauthorizedException` -> 401
`com.google.api.server.spi.response.ForbiddenException` -> 403
`com.google.api.server.spi.response.NotFoundException` -> 404

If you consume your endpoint in Android the error code will be in the IOException thrown there and you can react accordingly in the catch.

Comment: Yes I understand returning the HTTP error codes. What I wonder is how to deal with detailed error messages like violated constraints of domain properties.

Comment: This is not the behaviour I'm seeing in 1.7.5. I'm throwing a BadRequestException and the client's getting a 200 with my message String in the body as a bit of JSON.

Comment: Let me qualify that: this doesn't work on the locahost dev server, but it *does* seem to work on the App Engine server, even in 1.7.5. So that's a bug in the localhost dev server really.

Answer (score 3):

I tried something like this and seemed to work well for me.

```
class Response<T> {
   Status status; 
   String userFriendlyMessage;
   T object; //your bean or entity object

   RestResponse toRestResponse() {
      RestResponse r = new RestResponse();
      r.status = status;
      r.userFriendlyMessage = userFriendlyMessage;
      r.object = object;
   }
}
```

You cannot return a generic object from endpoint. So create an equivalent RestResponse class which can be created from Response.

```
class RestResponse {
   Status status;
   String userFriendlyMessage;
   Object object;
}
```

Status can be like this.

```
public enum Status {
   SUCCESS, RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND, RESOURCE_ALREADY_EXISTS; //etc
}
```

All your endpoint methods would return RestResponse which will in turn be constructed from a Response (T can be your bean or entity object).

When you deserialize your json response (RestResponse) you can straight away deserialize it as Response.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Sathya

Comment: This does not work for me, I get: "Error: Object type T not supported." Example: public Response.RestResponse getBeer() {
        Response<Beer> genericResponse =  new Response<Beer>();
    genericResponse.status = Status.SUCCESS;
         genericResponse.object = new Beer(“Carlsberg”);
        return genericResponse.toRestResponse();
    }

Comment: @dynamokaj - can you please post some code snippets ? You can link to github or some other document.

Comment: Yes here it is: https://gist.github.com/dynamokaj/cb0c0569311d9d15ee40 it should be like yours. However I have made the fields private and putted it into one file (ResponseDto.java) instead of three files.

Comment: @dynamokaj - i have a similar set up working. Can you try out the following - 1) make all fields in RestResponseDto public. (2) Remove T and make it a object in RestResponseDto. Let me know if that solves the problem. My working code is here - https://code.google.com/p/ishacrm/source/browse/trunk/CRMDNA/src/crmdna/common/APIResponse.java

Comment: Thanks, I changed RestResponseDto.object to Object instead of T and it now works like a charm. I have updated the Gist, but maybe you should update your answer to. Just change RestResponse.object to Object instead of T also, and then it works. Response.object should still remain as T so it can still be generic. Thanks!

Comment: @dynamokaj - Glad to know it works. I have edited my answer as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Im doing this by having an abstract class Entity.

It has a ResponseCode, which is an enum and a String ErrorMessage.

So "Book" could inherit from Entity. And your response could look like this:

```
public Book insertBook(Book book) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        if (containsShout(book)) {
            book.setResponseCode(ResponseCode.ERROR);
            book.setError("Object already exists");
        } else {
            mgr.makePersistent(book);
        }
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return book;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @davibq, but this does pollute the entity classes imo. Maybe I should create a SingleEntitiyResponse containing the model, response status and errors. Note that I can do the same for com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse by extending it and including similar repsonse status and errors.